# How to convert array value to non-object into PHP

Tags: codeigniter, postman, form-data

I have submitted this data with the postman form-data so how can I convert to non-object JSON from from-data array?

I have to try json_encode and json_decode but can't get json or non-object result into the controller.

In CodeIgniter controller.

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "first_name"

Janak
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

Kumar
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile_no"

123456789
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country_code"

 91
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_id"

test.mail@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123456
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_token"

123HFDT3434
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_type"

2
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="agency_name"

google
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
<?php
$content = <<<OUT
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

Kumar
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile_no"

123456789
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country_code"

 91
------WebKitFormBoundaryv6rwIfAWUgyyzeZF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_id"

test.mail@gmail.com'
OUT;

$clean = str_replace("\n",'',$content);
$parts = array_filter(explode('------',$clean));

$array = array();

foreach ($parts as $row){
    $parts2 = explode('name="',$row);
    $parts3 = explode('"',$parts2[1]);
    $array[$parts3[0]] = $parts3[1];
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I have a problem with your Array presentation as `"first_name"` would in fact be the value so I'm not sure if you've outputted your data correctly but let me know.